# Put a unique code on every page

Tags: luatex, counters, programming

I want to create a form that will be later filled on paper. Some fields though are filled automatically (i. e. printed already when person receives a form).

Here is an MWE for the form itself:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\BOX}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex,rounded corners=2pt]%
    \filldraw[
        color   =   black,
        fill    =   white,
        semithick
    ] (0,-.5cm) rectangle (0.5cm,.5cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \begin{minipage}[c][1cm]{6cm}
            \centering\sffamily\bfseries{}Code of the kit%
        \end{minipage}
        \tabularnewline
        %
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}[c][1cm]{6cm}
            \centering\BOX\;{\sffamily\bfseries--\;}\BOX\;\BOX\;\BOX\;{\sffamily\bfseries--\;}\BOX\;\BOX%
        \end{minipage}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have removed all the unnecessary for an MWE fields like `name`, `surname`, etc. The field `Code of the kit` should be filled automatically in the format `letter -- digit digit digit -- letter letter`.

I want to do something like `\MakeForms{100500}` and TeX produces 100500 pages, where every page is filled by the `next` code. Now, what `next` means: a code next to the `f120bg` is `f120bh`, after the `f120bz` goes `f120ca`, after the `f120zz` goes `f121aa`, after the `f999zz` goes `g000aa`, i. e. the order is lexicographical, but there are some letter that I want to be skipped, lets say, `e, u, y`, which means that the letter after `x` is now `z`.

**P. S.** If it matters, I want to use cyrillic alphabet for letters.

**P. P. S.** I use LuaLaTeX, so a solution using Lua code is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set up a nested loop.  Here I only use three such loops, to avoid getting too big, but you can logically extend it.  Second, I don't clear the page for each one, only start a new `\par` with a rule fill in between.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\BOX}[1][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex,rounded corners=2pt]%
    \filldraw[
        color   =   black,
        fill    =   white,
        semithick
    ] (0,-.5cm) rectangle (0.5cm,.5cm);
    \node(A)[right] {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand\code[3]{%
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \begin{minipage}[c][1cm]{6cm}
            \centering\sffamily\bfseries{}Code of the kit%
        \end{minipage}
        \tabularnewline
        %
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}[c][1cm]{6cm}
            \centering\BOX\;{\sffamily\bfseries--\;}\BOX\;\BOX\;\BOX[#1]\;{\sffamily\bfseries--\;}\BOX[#2]\;\BOX[#3]%
        \end{minipage}
    \end{tabular}}


\begin{document}
\foreach\DD in{1,...,4}{
  \foreach\EE in{A,...,E}{
    \foreach\FF in{A,...,C}{
    \code{\DD}{\EE}{\FF}\par\hrulefill\par
}}}
\end{document}
```

**THE BEGINNING**

[image]

**THE END**

[image]

While the business end of my method is embodied in

```
\foreach\DD in{1,...,4}{
  \foreach\EE in{A,...,E}{
    \foreach\FF in{A,...,C}{
    \code{\DD}{\EE}{\FF}\par\hrulefill\par
}}}
```

skipped letters can be achieved, for example, with simple modifications, like skipping the number 3:

```
\foreach\DD in{1,...,2,4,...,5}{
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you want to use something like `\themycount` for your code.

You can adjust the horizontal spacing using `outer sep` (for boxes) and `inner sep` (for hyphens).  Just for fun I showed an alternative way to center text in a 1cm space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\CODE}[1]% #1 = six digit number
{\bgroup
  \def\code{#1}%
  \ifnum#1<100000 \def\code{0#1}\fi% I assume you want leading zeros
  \ifnum#1<10000 \def\code{00#1}\fi
  \ifnum#1<1000 \def\code{000#1}\fi
  \ifnum#1<100 \def\code{0000#1}\fi
  \ifnum#1<10 \def\code{00000#1}\fi
  \def\decode##1##2##3##4##5##6{%
    \def\codeA{##1}%
    \def\codeB{##2}%
    \def\codeC{##3}%
    \def\codeD{##4}%
    \def\codeE{##5}%
    \def\codeF{##6}}%
  \expandafter\decode\code
  \tikzstyle{BOX}=[draw=black,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    semithick,
    minimum width=.5cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
    inner sep=0pt,% probably not needed
    outer sep=2pt]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.5ex]
    \node[BOX](A) {\codeA};
    \node[right,inner sep=1pt](AA) at (A.east) {\sffamily\bfseries--};
    \node[BOX,right](B) at (AA.east) {\codeB};
    \node[BOX,right](C) at (B.east) {\codeC};
    \node[BOX,right](D) at (C.east) {\codeD};
    \node[right,inner sep=1pt](DD) at (D.east) {\sffamily\bfseries--};
    \node[BOX,right](E) at (DD.east) {\codeE};
    \node[BOX,right] at (E.east) {\codeF};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\egroup}

\newcounter{mycount}

\begin{document}

\loop\ifnum\value{mycount}<5
  \stepcounter{mycount}

      \begin{tabular}{c}
        \rule[\dimexpr 0.5\ht\strutbox-.5cm]{0pt}{1cm}% centered 1cm
            {\sffamily\bfseries Code of the kit}%
        \tabularnewline
        %
        \CODE{\themycount}% already 1cm
    \end{tabular}
\repeat
\end{document}
```